# Generating numbers with unequal probability

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

Here is the thing.

I want to generate two values, 1 and -1, with different probability.
When I run this script, I get the message " choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'p'"

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?
Thanks.

```
from scipy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as r

def ruin_demo():


    tmax = 1000       #The number of game rounds
    Xi = 10           #The initial money the gambler has
    T = []
    M = []
    t = 1
    for N in linspace(0.3, 0.49, 100):     #The probability changing region

        meandeltaX = 1.0*N + (1-N)*(-1.0)  #The expected value for each game round
        M.append(meandeltaX)
        while (t < tmax and Xi > 0):

            deltaX  = r.choice((1, -1), p=[N, 1-N]) # The change of money during each game round
                #print deltaX
            Xi = Xi + deltaX
            t = t + 1
        T.append(t)
    plt.plot(M, T)
    plt.show()

ruin_demo()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the message `TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'p'` because [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) (the Python standard library function) doesn't have a keyword argument `p`.

Probably you meant [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
>>> numpy.random.choice((1,-1), p=[0.2, 0.8])
-1
```

You could fix your code by changing `import random as r` to `import numpy.random as r`, but using a non-standard single-letter name to refer to an important module is only going to confuse things even more.  The conventional abbreviation is

```
import numpy as np
```

after which `np.random.choice` works.

---

Now admittedly because `scipy` imports part of `numpy`, you can access `numpy.random` through it, but your line

```
from scipy import *   # <-- don't do this!
```

should be avoided.  It clobbers standard Python functions with `numpy` versions which behave differently, and in some cases give opposite answers.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try to run import numpy as  np and numpy.random.choice((1,-1), p=[0.2, 0.8]) in Terminal, I get the message" module  object has no attribute 'choice" why this happens?

Comment: @epx What's your numpy version?

Comment: @skyline75489  Thanks. My numpy version is 1.6.1 before. And I just upgrade it to 1.9.1 and this fixes the problem.